# Install 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. (rtl8188fu), or Netgear rtl8812au USB WiFi adapters

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, cinnamon

19 DEC 2019 - I really, really wanted to use the Cinnamon desktop to set up a new system my 83-year-old Dad could navigate. I struggled to get any USB WiFi device working with Debian using Cinnamon, gave up and installed Ubuntu, but still struggled (I think) because I had immediately changed to the Cinnamon desktop before attempting to get the WiFi device set up.

It just kept prompting for the password, no matter what fixes I tried. Not sure if Cinnamon was the problem, or if I just hadn't found the right solution online.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me with a fresh default install of Ubuntu 18.04:

1. Install default Ubuntu setup with a wired Internet connection.
2. Allow updates to install when prompted after initial login.
3. Open a terminal and execute the following commands:

   ```bsh
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install git
   git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu
   sudo apt install dkms
   sudo dkms add ./rtl8188fu
   sudo dkms build rtl8188fu/1.0
   sudo dkms install rtl8188fu/1.0
   sudo cp ./rtl8188fu/firmware/rtl8188fufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
   reboot
   ```

   For the Netgear rtl8812au, the following commands worked:

   ```bsh
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install git
   git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
   sudo cp -r rtl8812au  /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
   sudo apt install dkms
   sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
   sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
   sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
   reboot
   ```
4. After reboot, the WiFi network was recognized and I was able to connect.
5. I then installed Cinnamon using the following command:

   ```bsh
   sudo apt install cinnamon-desktop-environment lightdm
   ```

   (select the "lightdm" display manager when prompted)

...Reboot, then click the gear next to username to select Cinnamon before logging in.

After doing this, everything continued to work for me. Cheers, and happy holidays!

Comment: Could not complete your answer because it requires an username and password... =[