# "no wifi adapter found" in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers

how to fix "no wifi adapter found" in ubuntu 20.04 I am a new user in ubuntu  please help me !!!!

input- lsusb

output-

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2717:ff80 Xiaomi Inc. Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 214b:7250  USB2.0 HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 062a:4c01 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. 2.4G INPUT DEVICE
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: if you type "no wifi adapter found" in the searchbar above, you'll get many answers -ever tried it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 - No wifi adapter found DELL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249907/ubuntu-20-04-no-wifi-adapter-found-dell)

Comment: no output is showing, @Pilot6  please help me

Comment: Is it a USB adapter?

Comment: yes sir @Pilot6

Comment: Why you didn't mention it before? Then post output of `lsusb` TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: You have an RTL8188FU. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197223/install-0bdaf179-realtek-semiconductor-corp-rtl8188fu-or-netgear-rtl8812au

Comment: Thank you so much for help me a lot finally its work I am search this from a week finally I got it only because of you once again thank a lot. sir another one more request if you are using any social media please mention it I want to follow you.........@Pilot6